# Как подключить два разных View Controller [SWIFT]?

Tags: swift, swift3

У меня есть два разных `View Controller`, и в первом `VC` есть `UITableViewCell`, в другом `VC` есть одна кнопка, и когда пользователь вводит свои данные и нажимает Добавить - мне нужно, чтобы создавался новый `UITableViewCell` в первом `VC`.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что и как делаете?